# Time stamp program that exports to excel

Tags: java, excel

I am new to writing code, I wish to further develop my skills as a code writer by creating useful programs for myself and others.

For my first project i would like to write a program that fills in data to an existing excel sheet ("time stamp",date,name, etc...).

***What tools (coding languages, techniques,etc) do i need to learn to use, to make such a program?***

I currently know how to use basic java (polymorphism, recursion and basic dynamic data structure-lists,stacks,ques,trees), no gui stuff.

*Thank you!*

Comment: You can write an excel macro in VB to do it. Or you can write a program in any language (Python, Php, Java or anything ) to write to a CSV file, which can be opened in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work with Excel sheets you would need to use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) library. It is free and very handy for creating or editing Microsoft documents!

Here's a sample code for creating an Excel sheet and manipulating it:

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("New Excel with Java"));

//Create a workbook reference
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

//Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

//Iterate through each rows one by one
Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
```